# AWS Step Functions Data Limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am designing a state machine which will run two lambda functions that return each a Json array in parallel. Also, the result of these functions are then pass to two more lambda functions that will took those inputs and added to a database. I have all the functions ready and working separately, but when I execute the state machine it says that one of the executions failed because of DataLimitExceeded. I checked the documentation and it says that the limit for input or output results is 32.768 characters. The odd thing is that the execution that is successful is the one that the Json object returned is about 50k characters, and the one that is failing its about 46k characters. So, if both are exceeding the limit, why one of them is failing and the other one not!

```js
{
  "StartAt": "Sync",
  "States": {
    "Sync": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Next": "EnviarNotificacion",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "SyncClientes",
          "States": {
            "SyncClientes": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn...",
              "Next": "AddClientes"
            },
            "AddClientes" : {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn...",
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "SyncArticulos",
          "States": {
            "SyncArticulos": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn...",
              "Next": "AddArticulos"
            },
            "AddArticulos": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn...",
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "EnviarNotificacion": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Generally I'm not sure passing big data in the state machine is a good practice. maybe you should save it inside the Lambda, and pull it back on the next one

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, I did this first approach first because I wanted to have small functions doing very specific tasks instead of one big function. Also separating functions was helpful if I then needed to use the AddClientes or AddArticulos in other places. Still I kept looking and I cant figure out why one state is succeding and the other one not, when both had almost the same amount of characters and above the documentation limit!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well someone give me another solution which was good to me, so I post it here if anyone has similar problems like this. What I do was simple saving the data I needed in a file on S3, and on the second function I read this file from S3 and works just fine. One thing I noticed is that when I saved the files on S3, the data of the function that was working fine was 31kb while the one failing was 35kb so maybe the maximum size is 32kb and not characters as the documentation says.

Comment: Yes, storing the data in s3 is a good idea. Then the lambdas can just return JSON containing the s3 urls to the data.